# Using Control Vertical Scroller to Form a Marquee

Tags: .net, user-controls, scroll, scrollbar

I'm using MSVB2005. I'd like to write a user-control which is an automatic text-scroller, scrolling **fixed-text** vertically, in a smooth manner, e.g. pixel by pixel (and **not** line-by-line). This is also known as *Marquee* (in HTML, for example).

I've already implemented such a control using a timer, which upon each of its ticks, text is rendered onto control's surface 1 pixel up. It works very well, BUT consumes rather much CPU power, as graphical hardware acceleration is not used, and all rendering computations "fall" on the main CPU.

I'd like to improve control's performance by using graphical mechanisms built into the OS (i.e. Windows), such as Form/Control vertical scroller. I'm pretty sure the OS uses hardware-acceleration underneath.

I thought that my user-control could inherit from the *ScrollableControl* class, or from another class which inherits *ScrollableControl*, such as *Panel*.
I did that, and upon each tick of the aforementioned timer - the following is performed:

```
Y += 1
Me.AutoScrollPosition = New Point(0, Y)
```

where `Y` is a class-member, and hence increased by one upon each timer tick.
This works well too, BUT:

**1)** only if text-rendering is performed upon each call to control's `OnPaint` event-handler. If So... What was gained by this form of solution? (text-rendering seems to be the part that consumes most of the CPU time)

Is there a way to render the WHOLE text *only once* to control's surface, and have the OS fully manage the scrolling, i.e. let the OS automatically repaint the visible area of the control upon each move of the vertical scroller (without having to self-repaint the relevant part of the text on every call to *OnPaint*)?

**2)** The vertical scroll-bar is visible. I need it to be active but *not* visible.

Your assistance would be much obliged.

**P.S.**

The control is intended for a Winforms application, so I cannot switch to WPF right now.
I'm not familiar with DirectX and OpenGL, and wouldn't have the time to learn any of these technologies any time soon. so currently, a solution in any of these directions wouldn't be considered feasible. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for an optimization that's quite difficult to implement.  In particular hoping that hardware acceleration will help is off the table, text rendering is not accelerated.

Windows has built-in support for optimizing vertical scrolling, it is enabled by default on any modern Windows version.  It is a system-wide setting named "Show window contents while dragging".  Your requirements defeat that option, it is only available on windows that have a scrollbar and you explicitly don't want one.  Hiding the scrollbar on a ScrollableControl derived class is not an option.

The low-level winapi functions that implement that feature are however exposed, so you can technically pinvoke them on your own control.  The higher-level winapi function is ScrollWindowEx(), it scrolls the entire client area of the window.  This function also exposes the "smooth scrolling" feature, enabled by the SW_SMOOTHSCROLL option flag.  Beware however that you are unlikely to be able to use that flag since you cannot directly affect the *rate* at which that scrolls, you also indicated that you want to control the rate yourself by scrolling by a single pixel at a time.  You may well consider down-playing that requirement after you've experimented with this.

The lower-level winapi function that ScrollWindowEx() uses is also exposed, it is the ScrollDC() function.  It drops the requirement that the entire client area is scrolled.  And doesn't do anything to implement the smooth-scrolling animation.  It is unlikely you'll need it.

It is worth mentioning how these winapi functions achieve their optimization.  The trick is fairly simple, they directly bit-blit the pixels of the window, moving them by the scroll amount.  A basic operation that *is* hardware accelerated.  This avoids the need to have to repaint them.  You'll in essence get 99% of the pixels for free, give or take.

Text rendering is however still required, needed to render the pixels of the area of the window that got exposed by the scroll.  What is *very* important to make this fast is how much effort is required to figure out where to start painting.  It will be, for example, very expensive when you do something like word-wrapping text.  You don't know where to start painting until you've measured every line from the start of the text, calculating where the line breaks occur.  It will be fast when you can directly map the scroll position to a line number.  Or you keep track of the line break positions that you calculated earlier.

Just some hints here, your question wasn't specific enough about implementation details to judge whether these considerations apply.  You can use the pinvoke.net web site to get the pinvoke declarations you need.

Comment: Thanks much for the elaborate answer. I'm trying Bit-Blitting. I've read about it and successfully written an application bit-blitting between picture boxes, but could not bit-blit to form's client-rectangle / control's surface. I'm rendering the text only once to a Picture-box and then, upon each tick of the aforementioned timer, `OnPaint` is invoked, trying to bit-blit from the Picture-Box (with a vertical offset) to `e.Graphics.GetHdc()`. That does not work (an exception is thrown), probably because I should not use `GetHdc()`. What should I do? If possible, a snippet would be great.

Comment: Nowhere in my post did I recommend you doing the blitting yourself.  I recommended using ScrollWindowEx.

Comment: OK... So I'm testing `ScrollWindowEx` now. what structure should I use for the `prcScroll` and `prcClip` arguments (which according to MSDN should be of a `RECT` type, which is not available on my VB.Net)? How should this structure be casted to these arguments' actual type - `IntPtr`? Thanks much.

Comment: You'll find the declaration for RECT on pinvoke.net as well.

Comment: I've managed to work with the `RECT` structure, but finally decided to use NULL (0) for the `RECT` arguments, which means entire control surface should be scrolled. When I'm passing `Me.Handle` as 1st `ScrollWindowsEx` argument (i.e. `hWnd`), what was drawn earlier to control's surface simply disappears. What am I missing? Should I modify control _styles_ (`Me.SetStyle`) such as `UserPaint`, `AllPaintingInWmPaint` etc..?